# How to terminate an infinite console loop by letting the user press a specific key on the keyboard in java?

Tags: java

As you can see, it is an infinite loop, and I want to know if I could assign a key on the keyboard that terminates and stops this loop whenever the user presses this key.

NOTE that I am trying to do that in the console, not a UI

```
do{
  //some calculations here
}while(true);
```

Comment: IMHO you should learn not to rely on `while (true)` style loops, it's lazy and can cause lots of unintended issues and can be difficult to ascertain the conditions under which the loop should exit.  Instead you should have an "exit" value which you can toggle based on the user input

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was using `while(true)` because I was tired of re-running the code every single time I use it

Comment: Yes, so now try and use a `exit` value to control when the loop should exit based on your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Two examples of doing what you want:

First example:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    
    do {
        System.out.println("Type X to exit and hit enter");
        input = sc.next();
    } while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("x"));
    
    sc.close();
```

Second example:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    do {

        System.out.println("Type X to exit and hit enter");
        input = sc.next();
        
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            break;
        }
    } while(true);

    sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your console code to the while-loop; press 'a' or 'A' to exit.

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Type in "a" to end
    while (!sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
          // console code here
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting");
```

Comment: Good, simple example, Vanm.  Thank you for contributing this code as an answer.

Comment: My pleasure! hope to contribute more in future.